# Inline Visualforce page on master object page layout with detail object fields

Tags: visualforce, master-detail, inline

I was wondering if there is a way to create a Visualforce page to be used inline on a master object's page layout that has fields from a detail object.  For example, Object_A will be the master object and Object_B will be the detail object.  I am wondering if it is possible to add an inline VF page to an Object_A page layout that has fields from Object_B.  The usecase would be that there will only be one detail record for each master record.  If possible, it would save our users time in having to create a master record, then a detail record, and then return to the master record.  It would also allow the user to have all of their information in one page.

Anyone ever do anything like this?  Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: A built in way to do this is the use the Service Cloud Console. You have to pay for it though.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Thanks guys.  Do either of you have any code examples I could use for reference?